# Iterate over the output of `np.where`

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3D array and use `np.where` to find elements that meet a certain condition. The output of `np.where` is a tuple of three 1D arrays, each giving the indices along a single axis. I'd like to iterate over this output and print out the index of each point in the matrix that met the condition.

One way to do it is:

```
indices = np.where(myarray == 0)
for i in range(0, len(indices[0])):
    print indices[0][i], indices[1][i], indices[2][i]
```

However, it looks a bit cumbersome and I was wondering if there's a better way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `zip`

```
indices = zip(*np.where(myarray == 0))
```

Then you can do

```
for i, j, k in indices:
    print ...
```

For example,

```
In [1]: x = np.random_integers(0, 1, (3, 3, 3))
In [2]: np.where(x) # you want np.where(x==0)
Out[2]: (array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2]),
         array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2]),
         array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2]))
In [3]: zip(*np.where(x))
Out[3]: [(0, 0, 1),
         (0, 1, 0),
         (0, 1, 1),
         (0, 2, 0),
         (0, 2, 1),
         (1, 0, 1),
         (1, 0, 2),
         (1, 1, 0),
         (1, 1, 2),
         (2, 2, 2)]
```

Comment: What is significance of the * ?

Comment: The `*` is the [splat or unpack operator](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).  Since `np.where` returns a singular tuple of numpy arrays, the `*` allows us to pass each of the tuple elements as a positional argument to `zip`.  Note that for Python3, `zip` returns a generator, so be careful if not iterating over it directly (you may need to use `list(zip(...))`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was actually confused when I ran it using python 3. Your answer clarifies that anomaly.

Answer (score 5):

Use `np.transpose` over `zip`, it's faster for large arrays

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.random.randint(0, 7, size=1000000)
%timeit indices = zip(*np.where(myarray == 0))
%timeit indices = np.transpose(np.where(myarray == 0))

10 loops, best of 3: 31.8 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 15.9 ms per loop
```