# Obtaining pixel values within CV2 contours

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to get pixel values within contours. I've followed along with answers to similar questions but my results are off.

This block of code finds contours for an image and then iterates through them to find the contour containing the largest area. I added the ending if statement that tries to get the RGB value of the code if it is during daylight hours. The original image (video frame) is passed to a function I wrote (`grab_rgb)`, along with the contour.

```
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    (_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    # look for motion
    motion_found = False
    biggest_area = 0

    # examine the contours, looking for the largest one
    for c in cnts:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        # get an approximate area of the contour
        found_area = w * h
        # find the largest bounding rectangle
        if (found_area > MIN_AREA) and (found_area > biggest_area):
            biggest_area = found_area
            motion_found = True

            if not is_nighttime():
                rgb = grab_rgb(image, c)
            else:
               rgb = 'nighttime'
```

This is the function I wrote:

```
def grab_rgb(image, c):
    pixels = []

    # TODO: Convert to real code
    # Detect pixel values (RGB)
    mask = np.zeros_like(image)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, c, -1, color=255, thickness=-1)

    points = np.where(mask == 255)

    for point in points:
        pixel = (image[point[1], point[0]])
        pixel = pixel.tolist()
        pixels.append(pixel)

    pixels = [tuple(l) for l in pixels]
    car_color = (pixels[1])

    r = car_color[0]
    g = car_color[1]
    b = car_color[2]

    pixel_string = '{0},{1},{2}'.format(r, g, b)

    return pixel_string
```

The code runs, but returns only three RGB values, with only the second value containing anything meaningful (values 0 and 2 are [0,0,0],[0,0,0]. There should definitely be more than three pixels within the contours, so I'm not sure where I went wrong.

EDIT: I realized it might be helpful to include what is actually being stored in the variables.

mask:

```
[[[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...,
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [255   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...,
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...,
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 ...,
 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...,
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...,
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  ...,
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]
```

points:

```
(array([ 1,  1,  3,  5, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14], dtype=int32), array([ 1, 22, 22, 24, 24, 21, 23, 16, 20,  9, 15,  1,  8], dtype=int32), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32))
```

pixel:

```
[0, 0, 0] [136, 89, 96] [0, 0, 0]
```

pixels:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (136, 89, 96), (0, 0, 0)]
```

car_color:

```
(136, 89, 96)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like what you've asked the code to return is the RGB value of just the second point in the pixel values list (called 'pixels' here ) of the points in every contour passed to grab_rgb, with

> car_color = (pixels[1])
>
> ```
> r = car_color[0]
>
> g = car_color[1]
>
> b = car_color[2]
> ```

So the output should mean that your image has atleast three detected contours satisfying your area constraints, and that the RGB values of the second point in the contours' point lists are what you mentioned([0,0,0],[x,y,z] and [0,0,0]).

Comment: I added more info in the original post - but for some reason np.where is returning only three points. I'm assuming there is something wrong with the mask I am providing it. It's interesting that the first and last pixel values are 0,0,0. 


I pulled the second pixel value from pixels because it was the only one with a value that ever changed and I was trying to see if that was somehow doing what I wanted - but it wasn't. So I just can't figure out why np.where is only returning three points.

Comment: Don't think it should make a difference, but right now your mask is of the shape (width x height x 3) when you want (width x height x 1) . Don't do zeros_like since it gives your  mask the shape of your 'image', which has three channels and you don't need three channels.instead initialise mask of zeros using zeros(), giving it the width and height of the image yourself.
Also, your points array seems to have 11-12 points, so thats what np.where returned.

Comment: Fix the mask, and check this link to see how to iterate over output of np.where.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887138/iterate-over-the-output-of-np-where