# Is there a option to loop through np.where?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, where-clause

I have allready seen, that there are some questions with similar title, but this is not what I was looking for.

I need to create an array by `np.where()` with values from a list. Like that:

```
mask = np.where((LW_LK_arr == DG0_value[0]) | (LW_LK_arr == DG0_value[1]) | (LW_LK_arr == DG0_value[2]), LW_LK_arr, 0)


# etc. to (LW_LK_arr == DG0_value[215])
```

- `LW_LK_arr` is a array showing districts in Germany
- `DG0_value` is a list or 1-D-Array with 215 rows. Each row is one unique value (district number)... I need all in one where condition to create a mask with all 215 values.

I tried myself to loop, but i always overwrite the values by that....

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thank you for your answer! I am quite new in programming. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Have you taken a look at this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21887138/iterate-over-the-output-of-np-where

Comment: `mask = np.where(np.isin(LW_LK_arr, DG0_value))` ?  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

Comment: @RHP. Hello and thank you for answering. The solution in your suggestion is for `indices = np.where(myarray == 0)`, but i need it for 215 different indices.

Comment: @mikewatt Thank you so much! This seems to work. I was trying the whole day to loop this, not knowing that there is a function.

Comment: Glad that does the trick.  Avoiding Python loops is the name of the game when it comes to working with numpy :)